# conda build failing with need_source_download message

Tags: python-2.7, miniconda

I successfully built a package on the same Ubuntu desktop 2 months ago and am running into an error building the next version of the same package. I've updated the recipe and made sure conda itself was up-to-date before running the build as usual:

```
(base) pmena@pmena-7080=> cd anaconda_build/
(base) pmena@pmena-7080=> conda build mi-instrument
No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
WARNING:conda_build.metadata:No numpy version specified in conda_build_config.yaml.  Falling back to default numpy value of 1.11
Adding in variants from internal_defaults
INFO:conda_build.variants:Adding in variants from internal_defaults
Attempting to finalize metadata for mi-instrument
INFO:conda_build.metadata:Attempting to finalize metadata for mi-instrument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/bin/conda-build", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 474, in main
    execute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/cli/main_build.py", line 465, in execute
    verify=args.verify, variants=args.variants)
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/api.py", line 209, in build
    notest=notest, need_source_download=need_source_download, variants=variants)
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 2863, in build_tree
    notest=notest,
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/build.py", line 1837, in build
    output_metas = expand_outputs([(m, need_source_download, need_reparse_in_env)])
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/render.py", line 757, in expand_outputs
    for (output_dict, m) in _m.copy().get_output_metadata_set(permit_unsatisfiable_variants=False):
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/metadata.py", line 2054, in get_output_metadata_set
    bypass_env_check=bypass_env_check)
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/metadata.py", line 727, in finalize_outputs_pass
    permit_unsatisfiable_variants=permit_unsatisfiable_variants)
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/render.py", line 538, in finalize_metadata
    exclude_pattern)
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/render.py", line 390, in add_upstream_pins
    permit_unsatisfiable_variants, exclude_pattern)
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/render.py", line 378, in _read_upstream_pin_files
    permit_unsatisfiable_variants=permit_unsatisfiable_variants)
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/render.py", line 154, in get_env_dependencies
    channel_urls=tuple(m.config.channel_urls))
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/environ.py", line 749, in get_install_actions
    locking=locking, timeout=timeout)
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/index.py", line 172, in get_build_index
    update_index(output_folder, verbose=debug)
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/index.py", line 273, in update_index
    current_index_versions=current_index_versions)
  File "/home/pmena/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda_build/index.py", line 776, in index
    with tqdm(total=len(subdirs), disable=(verbose or not progress), leave=False) as t:
AttributeError: __exit__
```

This has always been a relatively straightforward process, so I'm hoping that it's just a simple oversight. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing a slightly older version of miniconda2, which I was able to find in [the anaconda archives](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/). The build completed successfully after that.